# How to group by a particular column and get the distinct set from it in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my node app, I'm querying postgres table which looks's like this.

```
id,file,start_time,expire_time,status
1,file_1,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
2,file_2,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 23:00:00,completed
3,file_3,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 24:00:00,completed
4,file_4,2021-08-13 17:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
5,file_2,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 13:00:00,completed
6,file_3,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 14:00:00,completed
7,file_1,2021-08-14 22:00:00,2021-08-15 215:00:00,completed
```

In the table, rows 1,2,3 and 5,6,7 are two same set of files and for those 2 sets, only the start_time is varying. So if u group by start time and take only the distinct set, finally the result should be like,

```
1,file_1,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
2,file_2,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 23:00:00,completed
3,file_3,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 24:00:00,completed
4,file_4,2021-08-13 17:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
```

So i have tried many ways to group them. But Still i couldn't get a correct result. Below is the query

```
select distinct on (file) * 
from glacier_restore_progress
where status='completed'
group by start_time;
```

and i get an error

```
ERROR: column "glacier_restore_progress.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `order by` not `group by`

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand correctly, you want one row per file based on either the earliest `start_time`.  If so, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (file) grp.*
from glacier_restore_progress grp
where status = 'completed'
order by file, start_time;
```

I notice that you got most of the way here.  The key is that no `group by` is used in this case, only an `order by` that starts with the `distinct on` keys followed by the ordering you want within each key.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd1ae9214aefce332a12afedcc3e7898) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: If you see the table structure, rows 1,2,3 are the records for a single request made by the user. Also there may be a chance that the user can make multiple other request for same set of files (ie rows 5,6,7). I need only one set from them which is the lowest start_time. And the only way to differentiate these sets is the start_time. Rows 1,2,3 have the same start_time and 5,6,7 have their own same time. Likewise there can be multiple sets of records for a particular file set which are having different start_times. So i need to choose one set among them

Comment: I hope you got my question, Also if the table only contains below records,
1,file_1,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 22:00:00,completed
2,file_2,2021-08-12 22:00:00,2021-08-15 23:00:00,completed
3,file_1,2021-08-12 22:55:00,2021-08-15 24:00:00,completed

The output should also same. Because rows 1 and 2 have the same start_time and row_3 have a different time

Comment: @ahkam . . . Your description seems equivalent to taking the first row per file.

Comment: Please try my second comment. When i run your query, I get only the first 2 rows. But the expected output should be both 3 rows. If a set contains a subset of files, both sets should be independent 2 outputs

Comment: @ahkam . . . I added a db<>fiddle showing that the solution does what you intend.

Comment: That's great. I have added 2 more rows to it with a different start time. In the output I would expect those 2 records too since both files are are having same start_time which is different from rows 1,2,3 and 4,5,6.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d37bd114be00a089567f4a2d6fdf0c08

Comment: Here the condition is, if the file name inside 2 different records are same, we see them as a single request. But if the file names of 2 diff set are a subset or sup set, we see them as 2 different requests

Comment: let me know if i can achieve this with a query or i need to handle it from my backend?